# How to get value of onclick= using xpath?

Tags: php, parsing, dom, xpath

I have a string that has lots of `<li>` sets of data. I want to get this value:

```
1: call.php?category=fruits&amp;fruitid=123456
```

inside onclick using xpath . My current xpath doesn't get me the onclick value so I parse it further to get my required data ! Could any one tell me what is the correct xpath to get value of onclick?

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($code2);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

// Empty array to hold all links to return
$result = array();

//Loop through each <li> tag in the dom
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('li') as $li) {
    //Loop through each <a> tag within the li, then extract the node value
    foreach($li->getElementsByTagName('a') as $links){
        $result[] = $links->nodeValue;
        echo $result[0] . "\n";
    }



    $onclicks = $xpath->query("//li/a/onclick");

foreach ($onclicks as $onclick) {
    echo $onclick->nodeValue . "\n";
}
}
```

data:

```
<li><a id="FR123456" onclick="setFood(false);setSeasonFruitID('123456');getit('call.php?category=fruits&amp;fruitid=123456&amp;',detailFruit,false);">mango season</a><img src="http://imagehosting.com/images/fru_123456.png">
            </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

`onclick` is an attribute, and you use `@attribute_name` to reference attribute in XPath :

```
$onclicks = $xpath->query("//li/a/@onclick");

foreach ($onclicks as $onclick) {
    echo $onclick->nodeValue . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this :

```php
$onclicks = $xpath->query("//li/a");

foreach ($links as $link) {
    echo $link->getAttribute('onclick'). "\n";
}
```